# Compare array to text file

Tags: java, csv

I have a text file: "example.csv" that contains 1000's of rows
The text file contains

```
Dog, 3123
Cat, 6544
Chicken, 8943
```

And another: "example2.csv" that contains 1000's of rows

```
Fruit, 3243
Banana, 9432
Chicken, 2043
```

And an array that contains (100's of rows):

```
Home, Dan, Dog, 4234
Home, Bug, Chicken, 3213
Home, Hds, Banana, 4324
Out, Bgh, Poodle, 3129
```

I need to change the third column in the array to the value found in the CSV, example.csv. If it is not found in the first one, it needs to look in the second one, example2.csv.

As you can see in my example, Chicken appears in both, but it needs to find the value from example.csv. However, Fruit only appears in the second, so it needs to find the value from example2.csv.

Anything not found in either csv needs to displayed that it does not exist.

Any example being:

```
Home, Dan, Dog, 4234
Home, Bug, Chicken, 3213
Out, Bgh, Poodle, 3129
```

BECOMES

```
Home, Dan, 3123, 4234
Home, Bug, 8943, 3213
Home, Hds, 9432, 4324
Out, Bgh, Poodle, 3129 : Display :Missing - Poodle
```

Thank you!

Number is the array and isFound starts off as false
Split by is: ","

Here is my attempt:

```
try {
    //Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new FileReader("Files\\"+"ABTutor2018Sem2"+".csv")); // import file
    brStudents = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Files\\deploystudio.csv"));
    brStudents2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Files\\deploystudio2.csv"));
    while ((line = brStudents.readLine()) != null) {
        arrSubjectsDeploy = line.split(splitBy);                      
        isFound = false;
        for(int h = 0; h < l; h++) {
            arrSubjects = Number[h].split(splitBy);
            line2 = "";
            errorMessage = arrSubjectsDeploy[0]; 
            if(arrSubjects[2].equals(arrSubjectsDeploy[0])) {
                arrSubjects[2] = arrSubjectsDeploy[1];  
                m++;
                tempHolder = "";
                isFound = true;
            }
            if(h == l-1 && isFound == false) {
                System.out.println("Missing: " + errorMessage);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is only trying to do the first text file ... but still does not work because it's looking at the contents of the textfile and seeing if it compares to the array, rather the the other way around.

Comment: which java version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map<String,String>` to store contents of `example.csv` and `example2.csv`. Then iterate over your input array to check if it exists in either file.

```
Map<String, String> firstFile = readFileAndConvert("Files\\deploystudio.csv");
Map<String, String> secondFile = readFileAndConvert("Files\\deploystudio2.csv");
int index = 2;
String[][] finalArray =
    {{"Home", "Dan", "Dog", "4234"}, {"Home", "Bug", "Chicken", "3213"},
        {"Home", " Hds", "Banana", "4324"}, {"Out", " Bgh", "Poodle", "3129"}};
for(String[] row : finalArray) {
  String valueToFind = row[index];
  if(firstFile.containsKey(valueToFind)) {
    row[index] = firstFile.get(valueToFind);
  } else if(secondFile.containsKey(valueToFind)) {
    row[index] = secondFile.get(valueToFind);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Missing " + valueToFind);
  }
}
```

`readFileAndConvert` function using java 8. But you can achieve similar functionality with any other version too.

```
private Map<String, String> readFileAndConvert(String path) throws IOException {
    String SEPARATOR = ",";
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
      return lines.map(line -> line.split(SEPARATOR))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(array -> array[0], array -> array[1]));
    }
}
```